# What is the default `routing` parameter for Elasticsearch's bulk api?

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk

From the [elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html#mapping-routing-field):

`The default value used for _routing is the document’s _id` (regarding PUT api)

But I could not find any default value for [bulk api documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html#mapping-routing-field)

Should I set `_routing` mapping manually or is there a default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the [routing value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-routing) in each command line

```
                                                 here
                                                   |
                                                   v
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1", "_routing": 123 } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Val. By the nature of our application, we need to upsert our documents. Until now we did not assign `_routing` mapping manually, so if we apply your suggestion, we -might- insert the same document into another shard, instead of updating it in the shard that it already resides. So the question is, until now, is this `_routing` field has been assigned randomly for us?

Comment: Yes, if you have not specified the routing initially, then it's been picked for you and you have no way of knowing on which shard your document landed. Either you do it right from the start or you need to reindex your data with routing into another index

Comment: Is such thing documented somewhere ?

Comment: Yes here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html